# Visual Studio Lightswitch Choice list query

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

When ever i define a choice list to a existing record and play the screen the old value is cleared leaving me a drop down menu to choose from the new choice list.
how can i keep the existing record and define a choice list in light switch?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the behaviour you are describing, but that is possibly because I have always veered away from choice lists in favour of lookup tables which are linked to the target entity via a foreign key.  Before doing anything else, I'd suggest trying that approach and seeing if you can get that to work.  If not, you could always create some custom code in your screen's _OnInitialize() method to reassign the currently selected choice list value to the target record, but this should not be necessary.

Comment: This is silverlight desktop project